# Self Join in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**I have the following Ticket Table**

```
if(!Schema::hasTable('tblticket')) {
    Schema::create('tblticket', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('TicketID');
        $table->string('Subject', 50);
        $table->integer('ParentTicketID')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('ParentTicketID')->references('TicketID')->on('tblticket');
    });
}
```

Primary Key is TicketID and There is another column called ParentTicketID, which is related to TicketID.

**Below is Ticket Model**

```
class TicketModel extends Model
{
    public $table = 'tblticket';
    public $primaryKey = 'TicketID';
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function TicketReplies() {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\TicketModel', 'TicketID');
    }
}
```

**Below is my Query**

```
$Ticket = \App\Models\TicketModel
    ::with('TicketReplies')
    ->where('ParentTicketID', '=', $TicketID)
    ->first();
```

I am trying to get all child tickets of a Ticket. but I am getting null.

Can you please guide if I am missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is my sample code, you can try this, I hope that will help you

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------
 * Relationship with same table, means recursive key
 * --------------------------------------------------------
 */


//this will get the childern against parent.

public function doseage_childs(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\DoseageForm', 'parent_id', 'id');
}


//this will get the parent against childern

public function doseage_parent(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\DoseageForm', 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

**Edited**

update your this method

```
public function TicketReplies() {
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\TicketModel', 'TicketID');
}
```

like this

```
public function TicketReplies() {
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\TicketModel','ParentTicketID' ,'TicketID');
}
```

and update your query model like this, because you already getting `TicketReplies` relationships.

```
$Ticket = \App\Models\TicketModel
    ::with('TicketReplies')
    ->where('TicketID', '=', $TicketID)
    ->first();
```

You relationship will works then